# Switching between local package and texlive package

Tags: fonts, texlive, paths

This question is about texlive 2017 under Windows OS. Some years ago there was change in the libertine package that broke my workflow. So I installed the older version of the libertine package in the texmf-local tree. Years passed and I'd like to have a look into the libertine package provided with texlive 2017.

I tried this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{/c/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/libertine}

\begin{document}
Huhu
\end{document}
```

Error message:  ``` LaTeX Error: File ``/c/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/libertine.sty' not found. ```

(One ` to much, never mind.)

How can I switch between the libertine package in texmf-local and texmf-dist? Preferably without deleting files.

---

If I change to a more »windowish« path line like this:

```
\usepackage{C:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/libertine}
```

there is a warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `C:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/libertine',  but the package provides `libertine'.
```

and an error message, starting with:

```
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/LinLibertine_I.tex))
No file libertine-dist.aux.
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/t1linuxlibertinet-tlf.fd)
[1{c:/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./libertine-dist.aux)name = LinLibertineT-tlf-t1--base, rootname = LinLibertineT-tlf-t1--base, pointsize = 
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!
Cannot find font LinLibertineT-tlf-t1--base in map file(s).

kpathsea: Running mktexmf LinLibertineT-tlf-t1--base.mf

The command name is C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32\mktexmf
Cannot find LinLibertineT-tlf-t1--base.mf .
```

Comment: Have you tried `/c/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/libertine`? At least in my TeX distro (TL on Linux) it is in a libertine subfolder.

Comment: @TeXnician Yes, I edited my question, thank you. Same error.

Comment: Can't you just rename the local version to something else, `libertine-old` for testing purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX Live now supports the idea of multiple local TeX trees using the [`conf auxtrees` target](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#conf-auxtrees---conffile-file-show-add-delete-value). You would therefore be best creating a dedicated local tree and adding/removing it as required

```
tlmgr conf auxtrees add C:\Users\me\libertinetree
tlmgr conf auxtrees remove C:\Users\me\libertinetree
```

---

Note this facility is modelled on a long-standing idea from MiKTeX, which can add multiple local roots either in the GUI or with similar commands

```
initexmf --register-root=C:\Users\me\libertinetree
initexmf --unregister-root=C:\Users\me\libertinetree
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of this, although I searched for exactly a feature like this yesterday. The whole old Libertine package consists of many files and so I'd like to have an ls-R file in this tree. The documentation says: > »The trees should not contain an ls-R file (or files might not be found if the ls-R becomes stale). « Is this to say, that there will be no automatic updates of the ls-R file or what is the difference to the usual behaviour?

Comment: @KeksDose The usual recommendation is not to hash local trees: they are small and not automatically hashed, so once you make an `ls-R` it might get forgotten.

Comment: --1.-- Made a new TDS-compliant tree and moved all libertine-legacy folders into it. --2.-- renewed all ls-R files --3.-- added the new tree using the command `tlmgr conf auxtrees add ...` --4.-- Tested, works. --5.-- removed the new tree `tlmgr conf auxtrees remove ...` --6.-- renewed all ls-R files --7.-- run updmap-sys via `tlmgr gui`, see under actions. Now I can test the texlive package of libertine, seems to work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a specific version of `libertine.sty` in this way will not change much, since the support files (fonts etc) will still be loaded from `TEXMFLOCAL`.

If you do *not* need anything else from `TEXMFLOCAL` the easiest way - not even changes in the document necessary - is to temporarily set `TEXMFLOCAL` to something not existing.

On Unix-like system this can easily be done with `export TEXMFLOCAL=/not-really-existing/`.

Since you are on Windows, setting environment variable is a huge pain, thus I recommend temporarily adding (or changing) `TEXMFLOCAL` in your `c:/texlive/2017/texmf.cnf`. If this file does not exist, create it. Settings there will override the defaults set by the TeX Live installation.

Comment: I suspected that there were no easy way. I have lots of fonts in TEXMFLOCAL. I love buying them and often enough a helpfull soul provides the necessary integration for pdftex. Recently I bought the Hesse Antiqua, published at the 100. birthday of the designer. However, I'll have an extra tree for this old version of Libertine.